# How to show form at start of function which closes at end of function?

Tags: forms, vb6, modal-dialog

I have a function which may take some time to execute.

How can I have a small modal form to show at the start of the function which closes when the function finishes?

Answer (score 2):

Say frmModal is the form you wish to show. At the start of your function put in

```
frmModal.Show
frmModal.refresh
```

At the end of your function put in

```
Unload frmModal
```

Answer (score 2):

My favorite trick for this is to put the code that is run into the form that is displayed while it is running. Then when it is done call Unload Me

```
'Code in Form1
Call frmWait.Show(vbModal, Me)

'Code in frmWait
Private Sub Form_Activate()

    'Do some work ...

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

when you load the form modal (form1.show vbmodal) then subsequent code is not executed until the model form is closed

a simple way (without api) to simulate what you want is to show the form modeless, and temporary disable the other form

have a look at the differences between command1 and command2 in the following test project :

```
'3 forms :
'    Form1 : name=Form1
'        contains 2 command buttons with the name Command1 and Command2
'    Form2 and Form3 contain nothing special
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim lngEnd As Long
  Form3.Show vbModal
  lngEnd = Timer + 5
  Do While Timer < lngEnd
    Caption = CStr(Timer)
    DoEvents
  Loop
  Unload Form3
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  Dim lngEnd As Long
  Enabled = False
  Form2.Show vbModeless, Me
  lngEnd = Timer + 5
  Do While Timer < lngEnd
    Caption = CStr(Timer)
    DoEvents
  Loop
  Enabled = True
  Unload Form2
End Sub
```